# Softlayer API: Understanding Product_Package_Server

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

What exactly is the Product Package Server? Would all the Product_Package's be represented in the Product Package Server?

I want to map a location name to every possible **Product_PackageID**. Currently I am getting all the valid datacenter names from **SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server** then filtering it through this REST request:

```
https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects?objectMask=mask[locations]&objectFilter={"locations":{"longName":{"operation":"Amsterdam 1"}}}
```

I want to know if I can get all my data (Location Name/ID, and Product Package ID) from just the Product Package Server REST request:

```
https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server) is a service dedicated to provide information about **Servers (Bare Metal Servers)**, in which you can find information about package, item/price and available datacenters for each server.

And [SoftLayer_Product_Package](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package) provides all information about Servers, Virtual Servers, Load Balancers, CDN and other available services. All the information displayed in [SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server) exists in [SoftLayer_Product_Package](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package).

Regarding to:

*I want to know if I can get all my data (Location NamIe/ID, and Product Package ID) from just the Product Package Server REST request:*

You can try this request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects?objectMask=mask[package[regions[location]]]

Method: Get
```